# Anyway to fix mathjs vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, node.js, mathjs

In `math.js` there are vulnerabilities where if a person enters a impossible question, `1:999999999999999999999`, it will crash the `node.js` process, any ideas?

The code I use for calculations:

```
let resp;

    try {
        resp = math.evaluate(args.join(" "))
    } catch (e) {
        return message.channel.send('Please provide a **valid** question')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a child process for running the calculations and limiting the maximum memory of processes on your OS, if you are using linux on a raspberry pi for example

Answer (score 0):

It's really absurd but if `1:999999999999999999999` is your only concern, I have noticed that / does not cause any problems but : does. So you could replace every `:` in your calculation with `/`.

```
let resp;

try {
    resp = math.evaluate(args.join(" ").replace(/:/g, "/"))
} catch (e) {
    return message.channel.send('Please provide a **valid** question')
}
```

Comment: But I don't know if there are any other impossible calculations that would crash your application.